# How to multiply list of tensors by single tensor on TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am implementing an RNN and contrarily to the examples I have found which minimize only the cost for the output in the last step

```
x = tf.placeholder ("float", [features_dimension, None, n_timesteps])
y = tf.placeholder ("float", [labels_dimension, None, n_timesteps])

# Define weights
weights = {'out': tf.Variable (tf.random_normal ([N_HIDDEN, labels_dimension]))}
biases = {'out': tf.Variable (tf.random_normal ([labels_dimension]))}

def RNN (x, weights, biases):
    # Prepare data shape to match `rnn` function requirements
    # Current data input shape: (features_dimension, BATCH_SIZE, n_timesteps)
    # Required shape: `n_timesteps` tensors list of shape (BATCH_SIZE, features_dimension)
    # We make a division of the data to split it in individual vectors that
    # will be fed for each timestep

    # Permuting features_dimension and n_timesteps
    # Shape will be (n_timesteps, BATCH_SIZE, features_dimension)
    x = tf.transpose (x, [2, 1, 0])
    # Reshaping to (BATCH_SIZE*n_timesteps, features_dimension) (we are removing the depth dimension with this)
    x = tf.reshape(x, [BATCH_SIZE*n_timesteps, features_dimension])
    # Split the previous 2D tensor to get a list of `n_timesteps` tensors of
    # shape (batch_size, features_dimension).
    x = tf.split (x, n_timesteps, 0)

    # Define a lstm cell with tensorflow
    lstm_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell (N_HIDDEN, forget_bias=1.0)
    # Get lstm cell output
    outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn (lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
    # Linear activation; outputs contains the array of outputs for all the
    # timesteps
    pred = tf.matmul (outputs, weights['out']) + biases['out']
```

However, the object `outputs` is a list of `Tensor` with `n_timesteps` elements, so the `pred = tf.matmul (outputs, weights['out']) + biases['out']` throws the error

> ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'MatMul' (op:
>   'MatMul') with input shapes: [100,128,16], [16,1].

. How can I do this multiplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to `tf.stack` the list of tensors into a 3d tensor and then use `tf.map_fn` to apply the multiplication operation on each 2d tensor along dimension 0:

```
    # Transform the list into a 3D tensor with dimensions (n_timesteps, batch_size, N_HIDDEN)
    outputs = tf.stack(outputs)

    def pred_fn(current_output):
        return tf.matmul(current_output, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    # Use tf.map_fn to apply pred_fn to each tensor in outputs, along dimension 0 (timestep dimension)
    pred = tf.map_fn(pred_fn, outputs)
```